# Unique limits in metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading through lecture notes and it was stated that if $(X, \rho)$, $(Y, d)$ are metric spaces and $f: (X, \rho) \to (Y, d)$, then if the limit of $f$ exists, then the limit is unique.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Consider two points $x$ and $y$. By the definition of a metric space, $d(x, y) > 0$. So a sequence can't get and stay arbitrarily close to both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: limits are unique in Hausdorff spaces, and metric spaces are Hausdorff. A convergent sequence converges to only one point (so the limit is unique). If the space was not Hausdorff, the same sequence could have more that one limit. It is not clear form your post if you understand the context and the term "limit of $f$", I would think they might mean the limit of a sequence $f(x_n)$, $n=1,2,...$

Comment: @jef Is there a rigorous proof of this?

Comment: @ySisanal I added an answer but maybe Mirko can add a proof for Hausdorff spaces (equally simple - just construct disjoint open sets around the limit $x$ and any other point $y$; thus the sequence must not eventually stay in the open set around $y$ so it can't converge to $y$).

Comment: @jef Yes that makes sense. Though, i was also confused on what was meant by 'limit of $f$'. Do you have ideas on that?

Comment: @ySisanal "the limit of $f$" doesn't really make sense. You could ask another question on this site that provides more context so we can figure it out. Also, if my answer answered your question, don't forget to accept it.

Comment: @jef It indeed answered my question. Thanks for the help. I'll think about it a bit before I ask another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "the limit of $f$". But we can see that any sequence in a metric space has at most one limit, which hopefully answers your question.

If $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $x \ne y$ then by the definition of the metric, $d(x, y) > 0$. Because $x_n \rightarrow x$, there is a $N$ such that for all $k > N$, $d(x_k, x) < \frac{d(x, y)}{2}$. Then by the triangle inequality $d(x, y) \le d(x_k, x) + d(x_k, y)$, we see that $d(x_k, y) > \frac{d(x, y)}{2}$. Thus the sequence $x_n$ doesn't converge to $y$.